# Inner Product on the space $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I would just like some confirmation on a problem and a small hint when starting the next.  The initial question is:

> Show that $⟨p,q⟩=p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$ defines an inner product on the space $P_2$  of polynomials of degree at most 2.

Here's my solution.

$$\langle p,q \rangle = \langle (p(1),p(2),...,p(n)), (q(1),q(2),...,q(n))\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)p(n) $$
For a degree 2 polynomial, this becomes $$ \sum_{n=0}^2 p(n)p(n) = p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2) $$
Therefore, this defines the inner product on the space of $P_2$.

The next problem is:

> Apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ for $P_2$  to construct a basis $\{p_0,p_1,p_2 \}$  that is orthogonal with respect to the inner product of the previous problem.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. If I could get a hint on how to set this up with respect to the inner product of the previous problem, I could figure the rest out easily enough.

Thank you.

Comment: For the first problem, they want you to verify that the given product satisfies the inner product axioms.  For the second one, you literally just follow the Gram-Schmidt algorithm starting with $\{1,x,x^2\}$.  What exactly are you getting held up on?  Are you familiar with the Gram-Schmidt algorithm?

Comment: @BobbieD, are you referring to the $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle v,u \rangle$, etc axioms? Those are the only ones I have available to me, I'm not sure how to apply them here.

Comment: @BobbieD For the second part, I'm not sure what they mean by "orthogonal with respect to the inner product of the previous problem."

Comment: Those are the ones.  For instance, to prove the one axiom you mention, just note that for every $p,q\in P_2$: $$\begin{align}\langle p, q\rangle &= p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2) \\ &= q(0)p(0) + q(1)p(1) + q(2)p(2) \\ &= \langle q, p\rangle\end{align}$$

Comment: They just mean use the GS algorithm with *this* inner product as opposed to some other one.

Comment: For the first one, that makes a lot more sense. For the second, do I just set, for example, $ \langle p,q \rangle = \{r_0, r_1, r_2\}$ and proceed with the algorithm?

Comment: I'll write up an answer on problem 2.  Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to perform the Gram-Schmidt algorithm:

Our new orthonormal basis will be $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.  But first let's just find an orthogonal basis $\{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$ and then we'll normalize it.

Start with $c_1 = 1$.  OK, the first one was easy.

Now for $c_2$, we want to take the second basis vector in $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and subtract out its projection onto $c_1$:

$$\begin{align}c_2 &= x - \operatorname{proj}_{1}(x) \\ &= x - \frac{\langle 1,x\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}1 \\ &= x - \frac{(1)(0) + (1)(1) + (1)(2)}{(1)(1)+(1)(1)+(1)(1)}1 \\ &= x - 1\end{align}$$

For $c_3$, we want to take $x^2$ and subtract out its projections onto $c_1$ and $c_2$:

$$\begin{align}
c_3 &= x^2 - \operatorname{proj}_{x-1}(x^2) - \operatorname{proj}_{1}(x^2) \\
&= x^2 - \frac{\langle x-1,x^2\rangle}{\langle x-1,x-1\rangle}(x-1) - \frac{\langle 1,x^2\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}1 \\
&= x^2 - \frac{(-1)(0) + (0)(1) + (1)(4)}{(-1)(-1) + (0)(0) + (1)(1)}(x-1)  - \frac{(1)(0) + (1)(1) + (1)(4)}{(1)(1) + (1)(1) + (1)(1)}1\\
&= x^2 -2(x-1)-\frac 53 \\
&= x^2 - 2x +\frac 13
\end{align}$$

Now just normalize each of these by dividing each $c_i$ by $\sqrt{\langle c_i,c_i\rangle}$ to get your $b_i$'s and you're done.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. One more question, though. For the integration involved with $\sqrt{\langle c_i, c_i \rangle}$, are the bounds from 0 to 2 because of $\langle p,q \rangle$ in the first problem?

Comment: @Kosta Why do you think there's an integration involved?  Remember $\langle p,q\rangle$ is defined (in the exercise) as $p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2)$.  So for instance $$\begin{align}\langle c_2, c_2\rangle &= \langle x-1, x-1\rangle \\ &= (0-1)(0-1)+(1-1)(1-1)+(2-1)(2-1) \\ &= 2\end{align}$$

Comment: Don't we use the following definition? $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$ for inner products?

Comment: That's just one particular inner product.  We're using a different inner product in this exercise.  In this exercise the inner product on $P_2$ is defined to be $\langle p, q\rangle = p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2)$.  There are infinitely many inner products.  This is the one we care about in this exercise.

Comment: So when do you know when to use the integral I wrote above and when to use something of the form given in this problem? (I apologize for trivial questions, I do not get much out of our lecture as my professor has a particularly heavy french accent.)

Comment: It should always be specified which inner product you're using -- except sometimes for $\Bbb R^n$ where if it's not specified it means $$\langle (x_1,\dots, x_n),(y_1,\dots, y_n)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$ as that is the so called "standard inner product" on $\Bbb R^n$.  But in every other case someone has to tell you which inner product you're supposed to use (or of course if you're working on your own problem then use whichever is most convenient).

Comment: My textbook uses the integral I listed previously in every example, is there a reason for this?

Comment: I guess your textbook author really likes that one...  But any bilinear function which satisfies all of those inner product axioms *is* an inner product.  And that's not the one that's used in this exercise.